# how to find the sum of array values in a multi dimensional array in php

Tags: php

My input array

```
$consumption = [
    'MONDAY'    => [
        'REFRIGERATOR'   => [
            3,
            9,
            7,
        ],
        'WASHINGMACHINE' => [
            2,
            4,
            2,
            8,
        ],
    ],
    'TUESDAY'   => [
        'REFRIGERATOR' => [
            5,
            3,
            8,
        ],
        'OVEN'         => [
            4,
            1,
            4,
        ],
    ],
    'WEDNESDAY' => [
        'TV'           => [
            6,
            9,
        ],
        'REFRIGERATOR' => [
            2,
            3,
            5,
            2,
        ],
    ],
    'THURSDAY'  => [
        'TV'  => [
            5,
            3,
            3,
            2,
        ],
        'FAN' => [
            4,
            9,
            8,
            5,
        ],
    ],
    'FRIDAY'    => [
        'WASHINGMACHINE' => [
            8,
            5,
        ],
        'OVEN'           => [
            3,
            9,
            7,
        ],
    ],
];
```

I need output as

Output:

```
Array ( [REFRIGERATOR] => 47 [WASHINGMACHINE] => 29 [OVEN] => 28 [TV] => 28 [FAN] => 26 )
```

Code attempt (pasted in from comments) [here is some pointless text so that Stack Overflow allows me to add in the code xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx]

```
  if(!empty($consumption))
   { 
      foreach($consumption as $key=>$val)
        { 
           foreach($val as $skey=>$sval)
           { 
              $outPutArray[$skey][] = array_sum($sval); 
           } 
       } 
    } 

   foreach($consumption as $k => $val)
   { 
     $result[$k] = array_sum(array_column($val, $k)); 
     foreach($val as $skey=>$sval)
     { 
       $result[$skey] = array_sum(array_column($val, $k)); 
     } 
   }
```

Comment: what code you have tried yet, show there.

Comment: Please post your attempts. What you have tried so far.

Comment: `array_sum(array_walk_recursive($array));`

Comment: if(!empty($consumption)){
 foreach($consumption as $key=>$val){
  foreach($val as $skey=>$sval){
   $outPutArray[$skey][] = array_sum($sval);
  }
 }
}
foreach($consumption as $k => $val){
  $result[$k] = array_sum(array_column($val, $k));
 foreach($val as $skey=>$sval){
        $result[$skey] = array_sum(array_column($val, $k));
 }
}

Comment: i tried the above. Is there any easy method without looping

Comment: You need to iterate over the $consumption array with a loop, and then for each day of the week, iterate over the device values for that day, adding the totals to a new array such as $total_values. Write the code and we'll help you debug it.

Comment: Can you paste your code into your question, it's easier to read there than in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Use a foreach loop.

```
$totals = [];
foreach($consumption as $day){
    foreach($day as $machine => $number){
        if(!isset($totals[$machine]){
            $totals[$machine] = array_sum($number);
        }else{
            $totals[$machine] = $totals[$machine] + array_sum($number);
        }
    }
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($totals);
echo '</pre>';
```

Live demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ad1f529f5b5428c4ea0b9dda2ed20a8baa657d5b

Comment: i need the output as  Array ( [REFRIGERATOR] => 47 [WASHINGMACHINE] => 29 [OVEN] => 28 [TV] => 28 [FAN] => 26 )

Comment: I added array_sum, sorry I got confused with your arrays being in one like :P

Answer (score 0):

I know its probably not the best way but you can use a multi dimensional foreach and put it in an array like this:

```
foreach($consumption as $consumption_value) {
    foreach($consumption_value as $key -> $value) {
        if(isset($consumptions[$key])) {
            $consumptions[$key] += $value;
        }
        else {
            $consumptions[$key] = $value;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code:

```
$consumption = array( 'MONDAY' => array('REFRIGERATOR' => array(3, 9, 7), 'WASHINGMACHINE' => array(2, 4, 2, 8)), 'TUESDAY' => array('REFRIGERATOR' => array(5, 3, 8), 'OVEN' => array(4, 1, 4)), 'WEDNESDAY' => array('TV' => array(6, 9), 'REFRIGERATOR' => array(2, 3, 5, 2)), 'THURSDAY' => array('TV' => array(5, 3, 3, 2), 'FAN' => array(4, 9, 8, 5)), 'FRIDAY' => array('WASHINGMACHINE' => array(8, 5), 'OVEN' => array(3, 9, 7)) );

$total_ref = $total_was = $total_oven = $total_tv = $total_fan = 0;
foreach($consumption as $key=>$products)
{
    foreach($products as $productName => $data)
    {
        if(isset($newarr[$productName]))
        {
            $newarr[$productName] = $newarr[$productName] + array_sum($data);
        }
        else
        {
            $newarr[$productName] = array_sum($data);
        }
    }
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($newarr);
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [REFRIGERATOR] => 47
    [WASHINGMACHINE] => 29
    [OVEN] => 28
    [TV] => 28
    [FAN] => 26
)
```

**Live Demo:  [Click Here](https://eval.in/684674)**

Comment: edited with dynamic code. please check it. @PraseethaVasappan

Answer (score 0):

check the [**demo.**](https://eval.in/684680)  result is,`{"REFRIGERATOR":47,"WASHINGMACHINE":29,"OVEN":28,"TV":28,"FAN":26}`

Hope it helps.

```
 <?php
    $consumption = array( 'MONDAY' => array('REFRIGERATOR' => array(3, 9, 7), 'WASHINGMACHINE' => array(2, 4, 2, 8)), 'TUESDAY' => array('REFRIGERATOR' => array(5, 3, 8), 'OVEN' => array(4, 1, 4)), 'WEDNESDAY' => array('TV' => array(6, 9), 'REFRIGERATOR' => array(2, 3, 5, 2)), 'THURSDAY' => array('TV' => array(5, 3, 3, 2), 'FAN' => array(4, 9, 8, 5)), 'FRIDAY' => array('WASHINGMACHINE' => array(8, 5), 'OVEN' => array(3, 9, 7)) );

    $result = [];
    foreach($consumption as $dayCon)
    {
      array_walk($dayCon, function($value, $key) use(&$result)
      {
         if(!isset($result[$key])) $result[$key] = 0;
         $result[$key] += array_sum($value);
      });
    }
    echo json_encode($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `foreach` like as

```
$result = [];
foreach($consumption as $v)
{
    foreach($v as $v_k => $v_v)
    {
        if(isset($result[$v_k]))
            $result[$v_k] += array_sum($v_v);
        else
            $result[$v_k] = array_sum($v_v);
    }
}

print_r($result);
```

[**Working Demo**](https://3v4l.org/o4R8u)